# How to add a element to the next list everytime a new value is entered?

Tags: list, nested

For example I have a list with a month and the month number, I want to add in another value in [0][1], [1][1],[2][1] every time I input a new value. I'm thinking of the append function however I'm unsure how to re-code that to make that value to input into the the next list along in the list.

```
list = [[['Jan'],1], [['Feb'],2],[['Mar'],3]]

def month():
    global list
    count = 0
    while value_count < 3:
        value = int(input("Enter a value: "))
        if value in range(101):
            list[0][1].append(value)
            count += 1
        else:
            print('Try Again.')
month()
```

I want to result with something like:

```
list = [[['Jan'],1,54], [['Feb'],2,65],[['Mar'],3,62]]
```

Where 54, 65 and 62 are random numbers a user has entered.

Comment: I think you need something like `list<list<string,list<int>>>`;

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comments in the code

```
# list is a function used by python to create lists,
# do not use builtins' names for your variables
my_list = [[['Jan'],1], [['Feb'],2],[['Mar'],3]]

def month():
    # print("Don't use globals!\n"*100)
    # you can pass arguments to a function, like in "def mont(my_list)"
    global my_list

    # cycling on a numerical index is complicated, use this syntax
    # instead, meaning "use, in turn, the same name to refer to each
    # element of the list" 
    for element in my_list:
        value = int(input("Enter a value: "))
        # if value in range(101):
        if 1: # always true, the test doesn't work as you expect
            element.append(value)
        else:
            print('Try Again.')
month()
print my_list
```

you can write the input loop like this

```
        value = 101
        while not (0<=value<101):
            value = int(input(...)
        element.append(value)
```

this way you'll miss the alternative prompt but it's good enough.